# Excel Hebrew formula

Tags: hebrew

If I put this following function into Excel, it will generate random letters in the given highlighted cells. 65 thru 90 is supposedly the excel defined values for the english alphabets from A thru Z.
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))

Now, Does anyone know how I can generate random hebrew alphabets? Does anyone know the excel defined values for the hebrew alphabets from aleph thru teth?.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1488 to 1514 but you need to use unichar instead of char